# How to read line of output with libssh

Tags: linux, ssh, libssh

In ssh cli, I can:

```
ssh root@localhost -t aria2c https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/archive/master.zip
```

it will show progress right now like:

```
ssh root@localhost -t aria2c https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/archive/master.zip
[#346e52 256KiB/416MiB(0%) CN:1 DL:262KiB ETA:27m6s]
```

but in libssh, when I run

```
ssh_channel_request_exec(channel, "aria2c https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/archive/master.zip")
```

no any output show in console, is there ssh_channel_readline to do that?

Answer (score -1):

I find it's aria2c reason, If I run code

```
ssh_channel_request_exec(channel, "apt-get update")
```

it will raise output line by line